# Как работать с set default для словарей в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

Как работать с set default для словарей в python? Что они делают?
Нужны пару примеров для начинающих.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все просто: вы вызываете [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) и указываете первым параметром ключ, а вторым значение, возвращаемое и устанавливаемое в словарь, если такого ключа нет:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> d.setdefault('Вася', "Пупкин")
'Пупкин'
>>> d["Вася"]
'Пупкин'
>>> d["12"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '12'
```

Другим вариантом будет [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Он позволяет для всех, несуществующих в словаре, ключей задать значение по умолчанию:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d['12']
0
>>> d = defaultdict(str)
>>> d['12']
''
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['12']
[]
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda x=None: "Вася")
>>> d['12']
'Вася'
```

Если брать обычный словарь, то для него аналогом из `defaultdict` будет:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> if '12' not in d:
>>>     d['12'] = int()
>>> d['12']
0
```